# Sending an Object* through boost::asio::buffer()

Tags: c++, boost-asio

Im setting up an asynchronus tcp server to handle many clients , all to be run on the same pc, server as clients. Each client will control a cube(an object or type Object).

For exemple, if i move a cube in one client, i should see it move in all the others

To achieve this, i need to send data about the cube's position, rotation and scaling from all clients to server.The object itself contain all that info. With the boost::asio::buffer(), i read that i can send a pointer as data.

My problem: it look like i cant send a pointer to the object itself through the boost::asio::buffer()

```
//message from client
const vector<Object*> t_data = {g_player};

boost::system::error_code t_error;

boost::asio::write(t_socket, boost::asio::buffer(t_data.data(), t_data.size() * sizeof(Object*), t_error));
```

it gives me an error about overload not matching the argument. am i missing something? is there anyway to send the server and other clients a pointer the the client object itself?

Comment: You can't send pointers over a socket, unless you send them to yourself (i.e. the exact same running process). It's not even possible to send to another process running locally from the same program (at least not on a system with virtual and protected memory).

Comment: what do you mean by unless i can send them to myself? And arent pointer , POD type? Which can be handle by the asio::buffer?

Comment: A pointer only has any meaning within your own program's memory space. Outside of your own program, in another program or on another computer, it's just a meaningless number. You need to send the _actual data_ that clients need for your application.